# Accessing variables w/in complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    var thisId = dropId+i;
    $("#p"+thisId).animate({ left:"+=32px" }, function(){
        if ($("#p"+thisId).position().left == 1024) {
            $("#p"+thisId).remove();
            window.console.log("removed");
        }
    });
}
```

In the above code example, by the time I get around to executing animate's complete function, `thisId` represents the last assigned value from the for loop NOT the value that I wanted to pass in for each iteration of the loop. Is there a way to get it to access the correct `thisId`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript does not have block scope. You can create a new scope by calling a function. E.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    (function(thisId) {
        $("#p"+thisId).animate({ left:"+=32px" }, function(){
            if ($("#p"+thisId).position().left == 1024) {
                $("#p"+thisId).remove();
                window.console.log("removed");
            }
        });
    }(dropId+i)); // <-- calling the function expression and passing `dropId+i`
}
```

Variables declarations area always hoisted to the top of the function. So even if you have the declaration inside the loop, it is actually the same as:

```
var i, thisId;
for(...) {
    thisId = dropId + i;
    //...
}
```

Every closure you create inside the loop references the same `thisId`. It's like in [Highlander](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Highlander_%28film%29): *"There can be only one."*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a closure around the current `thisId`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    var thisId = dropId+i,
        complete = (function(id) {
            return function() {
                if ($("#p"+id).position().left == 1024) {
                    $("#p"+id).remove();
                    window.console.log("removed");
                }
            }
        }(thisId));
    $("#p"+thisId).animate({ left:"+=32px" }, complete);
}
```

Comment: Technically the function expression you are calling immediately is not a closure.

Comment: Isn't it a closure around `id`?

Comment: A closure is a function which is executed in another context. Here you (a) are executing the function in the same context and (b) don't access any variable from th parent context. The function which is passed to `animate` is a closure, because it gets executed inside `animate` but has access to variables defined in your immediate function.

Comment: So the function returned from the immediately invoked function is a closure, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a closure... if you meant this one from the beginning, then you have been right and I apologize :)

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't using the word incorrectly. I was imprecise with my statement about it closing around "the current thisId" anyway.

Comment: I've always been using this term (closure) wrongly. I thought a function is already a closure if it just references variables in a higher scope. But afaik, the precise definition is that the function has to be executed in another context. The context it was created might not even exist anymore... something like that :) Anyway, I did not want to split hairs, but thinking again about correct terminology from time to time is good too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrapping what you had in an anonymous function should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    (function() {
        var thisId = dropId+i;
        $("#p"+thisId).animate({ left:"+=32px" }, function(){
            if ($("#p"+thisId).position().left == 1024) {
                $("#p"+thisId).remove();
                window.console.log("removed");
            }
        });

    })();
}
```